# how to change extension of all files in a folder?

Tags: windows

I have multiple files in a folder in below format.

"Filename1.drg.txt"

I want this to be changed to "Filename1.drg". How can I do that in command prompt?

I tried ren *.drg.txt *.drg. It changed them to "Filename1.drg.drg".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ren *.drg.txt *.
```

Will rename all files that end on `.drg.txt` by removing the extension. On this case, preserving `.drg`. Which is what you want I presume.

Comment: Yes. This is what I want it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
ren Filename1.drg* Filename1.drg

It works for me.

Comment: it changed the file name to Filename1.drg.drg